# How to use fork() in c on a file

Tags: c, fork, mmap

I am trying to divide up a large file and `fork()` to read each part of the file. My program already reads in the file and counts the total number of word occurrences in the file using a doubly linked list. Now I need to divide the file up into different sections and use `fork()` on each. I have already used `mmap()`, but I am not certain on what to do with it, or on how to implement the `fork()` on this file. I have seen `fork()` examples, but none of them seem to do anything besides create a child process and print the pid numbers. Does anyone know of any good examples that would help for what I'm trying to do? Or how I could implement this part?

Here is a part of my updated code:

```
             proc_num = atoi(argv[3]); // assign the PROCNUMBER to proc_num as an integer
             section = size/proc_num;
             // map file to memory and divide workload by passing different
             // starting address and stopping address to different processes
             if ((addr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED , file, 0)) == (void *) -1) {
                perror("ERROR: Mapping did not work!");
                exit(1);
             }
             char tmp_word[25];
             int  j, k = 0;
             addr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED , file, 0);
             char buf[proc_num][1024];
             // Create fork
             pid = fork();
             if (pid == -1) {
                perror("ERROR: Fork failed!");
             } else {
                for (i = 0; i < proc_num; i++) {
                   for(j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                      if(addr[i*size+j] != ' ' && addr[i*size+j] != '\n') {
                         tmp_word[k]=addr[i*size+j];
                         k++;
                      } else {
                         tmp_word[k]='\0';
                         // Count the words
                         count_words(tmp_word, words);
                         tmp_word[0] = '\0';
                         k = 0;
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
             kill(pid, SIGKILL);
             munmap(addr, size);
             close(file);
             } else {
                perror("ERROR: Not a file!");
                exit(1);
             }
```

Comment: [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) has detailed explanations about `fork`; but I am not sure it worth using in your case (your problem is I/O bound, not CPU bound)

Comment: Its my assignment though. I have to create different processes to count the occurrences of all words in a large file using fork.

Comment: Then, what did you try? Just call `fork`, keep its result, and handle the three cases: `<0` on failure, `==0` in child process, `>0` in parent process...

Comment: The problem is on how to divide up the workload by passing in different starting and stopping addresses to different processes. I'm lost on this.

Comment: if you `fork()` it keeps all the variables(copy of the adress space) you have declared before hand. you can easily just divide it before the fork and then `fork()` keeping a counter on how many forks you have done. note though that the processes do NOT share memory.

Comment: Read much more about [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). The child process has its address space (and other things: file descriptor table) be a *copy* of the address space of the parent process. So any variable (except the result of `fork`) & heap data has the same value just after the `fork` as it has just before it.

Comment: @rowan.G So what is it from the mmap() function above that I use? Say I want to divide the file into two processes...each one going through different halves of the file...how do I know where to start and stop? Right now it has the entire file.

Comment: just define some offsets? depending on the filesize `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`. depending how you want to read you can just `fork` once and the parent process reads from 0 to filesize / 2 and the child reads from filesize / 2 + 1 to EOF

Answer (score 0):

(I don't really get your code, where is the fork?)

I don't think is a good idea read one file from 2 sibling processes.

From fork(2):

```
 The child inherits copies of the parent’s set of open file  descrip-
 tors.   Each  file  descriptor  in the child refers to the same open
 file description (see open(2)) as the corresponding file  descriptor
 in  the parent.  This means that the two descriptors share open file
 status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O  attributes
 (see the description of F_SETOWN and F_SETSIG in fcntl(2)).
```

This means that if you open the file before you fork the process, the processes will share the file descriptors.

If the file descriptors are shared and you want to use several processes to read the file you need to seek the cursor every time a process attempts to read the file. And that call should be protected by a mutex, so probably is not a good solution.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to implement the fork for what I need to do, thats why its not in the code. So you are saying I should call fork() before opening the file? How would I divide up the file then?

Comment: I was saying that use 2 processes to read a single file is not a good idea. furthermore I don't think this will speedup the reading: it's the reading itself that is slow. 
You really need to use 2 processes?

Comment: I need to test it with 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16 processes and compare the performance.

Comment: No way. The bottleneck is the I/O dude. You are going to stop all your cpu reading the same file. Is a suicide. This is not an operation that is worth to parallelize

Comment: Each process needs to read a different part of the file, count all word occurrences, and then sort the results. Its what I was assigned.

Comment: That is suppose to be the "hello world" of the Hadoop framework. Word count

Comment: Anyway, my answer is still correct, if you fork after the open you need to seek every time the cursor. So fork the process before the file opening (but still check the fd)

Comment: The code is reading through a memory map. No seeking involved.